# WebRTC video stream error

Tags: javascript, video, stream, webrtc

I'm trying to make a WebRTC video-conference service, and it seems to work, I've receive the other peer stream, but the video is not reproducing.

This is the JavaScript code:

```
    var localStream, localPeerConnection, remotePeerConnection;

    localPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection( null );

    localPeerConnection.onaddstream = function ( event ) {
        // Here is where I receive the other Peer stream
        remote.src = URL.createObjectURL( event.stream ); 
        remote.play();
    }; 

    var local  = document.getElementById('person1'),
        remote = document.getElementById('person2');

    navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }, function ( stream ) {
        local.src = URL.createObjectURL( stream );
        localPeerConnection.addStream( stream );
        localStream = stream;
    }, function ( error ) {
        alert("Error getting your data");
        console.log( "ERROR OCURRED: " + error );
    });


    function createUser () {
        localPeerConnection.createOffer( function ( desc ){
            localPeerConnection.setLocalDescription( desc );
            socket.emit('newConnection', { description: desc });
        });
    };

    socket.on('newUser', function ( description ) {

        localPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription( new RTCSessionDescription( description.description ), function () {

            localPeerConnection.createAnswer( function ( desc ) { 
                localPeerConnection.setLocalDescription( desc ); 
            }, function ( err ) { 
                console.log( err ) 
            });

        }, function ( err ) { 
            console.log(err); 
        });

    });
```

I don't know why this is happening. The function createUser() is called to start the call. The peer who start the call doesn't get the event `onaddstream`, maybe that's the problem. When the peer who answer the call, gets the `onaddstream` event, the function is called, and the stream which receives is the same that the other peer is generating.

Thank's advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you are handling 'newConnection' on clientside. You are just emitting that only. I think

```
socket.on('newUser', function ( description ) {
```

should be changed to

```
 socket.on('newConnection', function ( description ) {
```